# Setting 'KeepForever' for a TFS Release

Tags: c#, azure-devops, release-management

I use [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Release.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Release.Client/) to modify TFS Releases from C# Code. I use Version 16.143.2 of the ClientLibrary and TFS2017Update2.
I just want to modify the KeepForever flag of a release, but it does not work.
The updated release, that is returned by the method 'UpdateReleaseAsync' always has the 'old' value for KeepForever.
This is my code:

```
    public void SetReleaseRetainIndefinitely(ReleaseHttpClient releaseClient, Release release, string tfsProjectName, bool retain)
    {
        release.KeepForever = retain;
        var task = releaseClient.UpdateReleaseAsync(release, tfsProjectName, release.Id);
        var updatedRelease = task.Result;
        if (updatedRelease.KeepForever == retain)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Set 'Retain Indefinitely' to {retain}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to set 'Retain Indefinitely' to {retain}");
        }
    }
```

Any hints what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **UpdateReleaseResourceAsync** method with **ReleaseUpdateMetadata** instead

Comment: This does work, but I wonder why my original approach does not?
My problem with the ClientLibraries is that there are always 1000 ways to do something, but 999 are not working!

Comment: @PainElemental The requests' methods are different, one is PUT and another is PATCH.